# Which is better; Olive oil or Clarified butter(Ghee)?

Tags: nutrition, dairy, healthy-cooking

More specifically, if Person A consumed a certain amount of food cooked with olive oil every day, and if Person B consumed the same amount of food cooked with ghee/clarified butter every day, which person would be subjected to a lesser risk of heart disease?

It's an age old argument within our family that I'd look forward to getting cleared. I'd greatly appreciate reliable sources/citations to any answers!

Comment: Ghee is higher in saturated fat.  Saturated is generally considered less healthy.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The question is really difficult to answer as no one has ever done a study with probates either only eating olive oil butter or ghee clarified butter. Are you interested in saturated fat vs. non saturated fat, or educated guessing or links to actual studies? I think it would be best to [edit] your question so that it is easier to answer.